# Using libcurl on 32bit Windows

Tags: c++, compilation, libcurl

I'm trying to compile with libcurl on a 32bit windows install. I'm using mingw as a compiler. I downloaded libcurl from https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vszakats/generic/curl-7.58.0-win32-mingw.7z and am using this to compile my project:

```
g++ -o test.exe -g just_get_output.cpp http_requests.cpp -L C:\curl-7.58.0-win32-mingw\lib -lcurl -lpsapi
```

All the libcurl code is in http_requests.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>

// https://kukuruku.co/post/a-cheat-sheet-for-http-libraries-in-c/

int http_post(char* url, char* data)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) 
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

My main body of code, heavily redacted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "http_requests.cpp"

int main( void ) {
    std::string info = "test";
    std::string url = "192.168.30.1:8080";
    http_post(url, info)
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Z:\>g++ -o test.exe -g just_get_output.cpp http_requests.cpp -L C:\curl-7.58.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a -lcurl -lpsapi
In file included from just_get_output.cpp:11:0:
http_requests.cpp:3:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
http_requests.cpp:3:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is going on? My precompiled libcurl.a is in the right directory, I'm linking it properly using -L and -l, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: This is a compile not a link error, it's expecting the directory above `curl/curl.h` to be on the include path.

Comment: Ahh ok, this is my first time compiling C++ with third party libraries. How do I fix that?

Comment: Actually I did manage to google this--for anyone else looking, you can use -I (capital I) to link to C:\curl-7.58.0-win32-mingw\include

Thank you @RichardCritten!

Comment: You should now answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

This is a compile error. It's expecting the directory above curl/curl.h to be on the include path.

For anyone else looking, you can use -I (capital I) to link to C:\curl-7.58.0-win32-mingw\include. Thank you @RichardCritten!

Answer (score 1):

As always, you should **read [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html)**:

> **Compiling the Program**
>
> Your compiler needs to know where the libcurl headers are located. Therefore you must set your compiler's include path to point to the directory where you installed them. The 'curl-config'[3] tool can be used to get this information:
>
> $ curl-config --cflags

I haven't used libcurl but, based on this page, I think what you *should* be executing is this:

```
g++ -o test.exe -g \
   just_get_output.cpp http_requests.cpp \
   `curl-config --cflags` \
   `curl-config --libs`
```

Now the required parameters will be emplaced properly for you.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I did read this, but I was under the impression curl-config was a command line tool that I had to run, and I couldn't figure out how to run it on windows. I don't have curl installed on the windows machine, I just have the items included in the zip file I downloaded from the link above.

Comment: @E.Browning: It _is_ a command-line tool that you have to run, just like `g++`. You should perform the installation properly. If really desperate you can stick to the hardcoded flags, but among them must be the include path.

Comment: How? There are no directions on the site for how to get curl-config installed--I was under the impression I just needed to use the items from the zip file and tell the compiler and linker where it all is. Am I wrong?

Comment: You didn't tell the compiler where it all is. You did not provide the include path.

Comment: The specific page you linked does not contain installation instructions for libcurl. It contains usage instructions for libcurl assuming it's already on a system. Their download page doesn't, either, and when I've downloaded the correct zip files that are precompiled for my system, it doesn't come with curl-config as far as I can see. Could you please provide more guidance if you are familiar with using libcurl on win32? I'd be happy to get it installed properly if this way is incorrect.

Comment: Actually, I double checked because I knew I had read this somewhere. curl-config is not available on windows:

"On unix-like machines, there's a tool named curl-config that gets installed with the rest of the curl stuff when 'make install' is performed."

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html

Comment: You have it if you're using MinGW (effectively producing a UNIX-like machine for your purposes here). Note that GCC is also for Unix-like machines yet you're already using that.

Comment: Do I need to compile libcurl from scratch then? I'm not sure what you mean by "properly install".